# Django Nginx - how to configure/redirect urls from subdomain

Tags: django, nginx, dns, nginx-config

lets suppose I have a site and the domain is **mydomain.com**, I want to create a subdomain **sub.mydomain.com** that references/redirect to **mydomain.com/sub** how would I do that, is this a nginx or django configuration?

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sub/', include('sub.urls', namespace='sub'))
]
```

for example is there a way to make the django recognize the subdomain and then include the `sub.urls` or do I need to do it by nginx

my configuration of /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jamelaumn.com *.jamelaumn.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jamelaumn.com *.jamelaumn.com;
    ssl_certificate aaaaaaaaaaaaa/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key zzzzzzzzzzzzz/privkey.pem;


    location /static/ {
        alias /home/jamelaumn/myproject/deploystatic;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/jamelaumn/myproject/media;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```